# Border not showing for Button Group with hidden Button

Tags: visualforce, css, lightning-design-system, css3

I have a Button Group with three buttons in it.  However the left most Button is hidden by default and only becomes visible when the center Button is clicked. My problem is that the left border of the center Button / Button Group is not visible when the left most button is hidden.  I'm using the class "slds-hide" to hide the button.

My Button Group with all buttons in it.

```
<div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-hide" onclick="saveContact();" id="saveButton">Save</button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="editContact(this);">Edit</button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="launchApp();" >Launch App</button>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
function editContact(button)
{
    if(button.textContent === 'Edit')
    {
        button.textContent = 'Cancel';
    }else
    {
        button.textContent = 'Edit';
    }
    document.getElementById('saveButton').classList.toggle('slds-hide');
}
```

A picture of my Button Group without the left border.

[image: Left Border Missing]

A picture of my Button Group with border and all buttons visible

[image]

What can I do to ensure that the left border of the Button Group will always be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumed approach appears to be to disable rather than hide as illustrated in the [Button Groups](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-groups/) documentation. (Bootstrap button groups also don't support the hide approach.)

When `disabled` is added:

```
<button disabled="" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Save</button>
```

your buttons appear like this:

[image: disabled button screen shot]

Comment: Thank you.  I'm quite new to the whole HTML/CSS + Javascript stuff, I'll keep this kind of thing in mind in the future.

Comment: @DougB My suggestion is to stick to the combinations that are documented; hopefully over time there will be more Salesforce documentation and 3rd party examples posted of less standard things.